# Narrowing results in SQL

Tags: sql

I've built a query in SQL, but I want to further narrow my results and can't figure out how to do it. Not sure if I need to use a Case statement or not? I used a WITH just because it is easier for me to reference the new column I created with my case statement.

Here is my code:

```
WITH Analysis as (
SELECT
MPOINTNAME
,eff_date as MPEFFDATE
,end_date as MPENDDATE
,CASE
When `eff_date = '01-NOV-21' Then 'New detail'
when end_date = '01-OCT-21' Then 'Expired detail'
End detail
FROm Measurementpoint
GROUP BY MPOINTNAME, eff_date, end_date )

SELECT
a.mpointname
,a.mpeffdate
,a.mpenddate
,a.detail`
From Analysis a
order by a.mpointname
```

Here is the output:

```
MPOINTNAME `MPEFFDATE `MPENDDATE `Detail`
11-15       01-NOV-21`  01-DEC-12`  New detail`
11-15       01-NOV-20   01-OCT-21` `Expired detail`
06-15       01-NOV-21   01-DEC-12   New detail`
03-15       01-NOV-21`  01-DEC-12`  New detail
03-15       01-NOV-20   01-OCT-21` `Expired detail`
07-15       01-NOV-21   01-DE-12C   New detail`
```

Now, I want to only include the MPOINTNAME that only have a 'New detail'. This tells me it is brand new, whereas the others are just a new detail, but they had an expired detail from the month prior. I don't know how to just get those results. Essentially I'd only want two lines displayed, the third one and the last one. Our system defaults the end date on new details to 01-Dec-12.
Thanks
Marc

`

Comment: First off all, using string constants is a really (REALLY) bad way for future work, but that aside:
If I'm correct you ONLY want 06-15 and 07-15 showing up (from the list you mention) as "New detail" right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't really answer my comment, so this is assuming (and assumptions are ..), but I assume you want 06-15 and 07-15 from the list you mention above.

You already have a CTE : Analysis , which will make things a lot easier.. What you want is a selection of ID's NOT in a subselect; like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Analysis 
WHERE MPOINTNAME NOT IN 
    (SELECT MPOINTNAME FROM Analysis WHERE Detail = 'Expired detail')
```

Using * as an easy go-to, do whatever you want there. But you can use this CTE multiple times, so you could also use it to query the "ID" (or in this case "MPOINTNAME") you don't want.

That being said - using string literals like "eff_date = '01-NOV-21'" really grinds my gears, if it's a date you could use a different (future-proof) format - but that's up to you.

Comment: If this did answer your question please mark as resolved for other people.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I also appreciate the advice on string literals. I'm new to this, so all the advice is appreciated.